# Java - How to connect using SOCKS5

Tags: java, sockets, torsocks

How can I create a socket connection using a SOCKS5 proxy with Java?

I have found several ways of connecting with socks4 but no one with socks5. Is this possible in Java?

This is what I got so far, but it doesn't seem to work. When I try to connect with the socket, it stays forever until it says connection time out.

```
SocketAddress sa = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("127.0.0.1", TOR_SOCKS_PORT);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, sa);
return new Socket(proxy);
```

Comment: [https://github.com/fengyouchao/sockslib](https://github.com/fengyouchao/sockslib) client\server lib implementation

Comment: Unfortunatelly, that library is still being developed and doesn't work yet.

Comment: When you try to connect to what with the socket using what code?